# IBM Cloud: "Unauthorized" error when importing key into Key Protect using Terraform

Tags: terraform, ibm-cloud, terraform-provider-ibm, key-protect

I am using Key Protect on IBM Cloud. I want to import an existing root key into my Key Protect instance using Terraform. I am following the documentation for [ibm_kms_key](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/IBM-Cloud/ibm/latest/docs/resources/kms_key#import):

```
data "ibm_resource_instance" "kms_instance" {
  name     = "henrikKeyProtectUS"
  service  = "kms"
  location = "us-south"
}

resource "ibm_kms_key" "key" {
  instance_id = data.ibm_resource_instance.kms_instance.guid
  key_name       = "mytestkey"
  standard_key   = false
  payload = "rtmETw5IrxFIkRjl7ZYIxMs5Dk/wWQLJ+eQU+HSrWUo="
}
```

While applying the changes, Terraform returns with an error:

```
ibm_kms_key.key: Creating...
╷
│ Error: Error while creating Root key with payload: kp.Error: correlation_id='618f8712-b357-xxx-af12-155ad18fbc26', msg='Unauthorized: The user does not have access to the specified resource'
│ 
│   with ibm_kms_key.key,
│   on main.tf line 7, in resource "ibm_kms_key" "key":
│    7: resource "ibm_kms_key" "key" {
```

Why? I am the account owner and Key Protect instance administrator. I should have all the privileges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is actually described in the introduction to [ibm_kms_key](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/IBM-Cloud/ibm/latest/docs/resources/kms_key), but easily overread. The set region for the provider currently has to match the region of the KMS instance.

After switching my provider from "eu-de" to "us-south", too, I was able to import the key.

```
provider "ibm" {
  ibmcloud_api_key = var.ibmcloud_api_key
  region           = "us-south"
  ibmcloud_timeout = var.ibmcloud_timeout
}
```